# how to run a video clip using asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to embed video player in asp.net which can support multi video formats and can run same format clip in different browsers.
i.e mp4/ogg clip can be played on firfox as well as on chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with asp.net (this is pure html stuff), just write out a html video tag

[html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/)

[diveintohtml5](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html)

Comment: html video tag is not supported in old browses and other thing is that if i am using html video tag i will have to upload more than one format video clip for each video clip.

Comment: Of course you will have to upload more than 1 format, even with html5 video you would. Use flash video then, but a lot of ppl are deactivating flash these days (me included) ..so what choice do you have ?

Comment: but most of the websites like youtube, facebook use flash player for video streaming but I don't know how to use flash player and cant find a good tutorial for using flash in asp. I found but but it is only playing .flv file.

Comment: youtube uses html5 video with alternate formats and a fallback to flash, so yes, they use at least 3 or 4 formats. Either you use multiple formats, or you use flash, or you install a streaming video server with transcoding capabilities.

Comment: Also Flash has nothing to do with asp. At best you just dynamically write out the name of the video file. I don't see how writing some pure html qualifies as a .NET question.  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/simple-html5-video-flash-fallback-custom-controls/

Comment: what i know is that youtube convert the uploaded clip in .flv to play it with flash player, I am thinking to use flash player but i have no idea of how to use it and how will i convert other format clips in .flv

Comment: Really ? Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=video+converters, Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+flash+tag

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this simple code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="videoSource.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all)

You can use swf files, if you want, in this way:

```
<embed src="sourceSWF.swf" height="200" width="200">
```

Good luck!

Comment: <source src="videoSource.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
this is the problem I will have to upload 2 copies of each video clip need a player which can run one format file on different browsers